# What's the difference between cuDeviceCanAccessPeer(...) and cuDeviceGetP2PAttribute(..., CU_DEVICE_P2P_ATTRIBUTE_ACCESS_SUPPORTED, ...)?

Tags: cuda, multi-gpu

I don't have access to a multi-gpu system to test this, but in cuda.h I found two things that seems quite similar. The first is the function

```
    CUresult CUDAAPI cuDeviceCanAccessPeer(int *canAccessPeer, CUdevice dev, CUdevice peerDev);
```

Described as

> Returns in `*canAccessPeer` a value of `1` if contexts on `dev` are capable of directly accessing memory from contexts on `peerDev` and `0` otherwise. If direct access of `peerDev` from `dev` is possible, then access may be enabled on two specific contexts by calling `::cuCtxEnablePeerAccess()`.

And the second one is

```
    CUresult CUDAAPI cuDeviceGetP2PAttribute(int* value, CUdevice_P2PAttribute attrib, CUdevice srcDevice, CUdevice dstDevice);
```

Described as

> Returns in `*value the` value of the requested attribute `attrib` of the link between `srcDevice` and `dstDevice`. The supported attributes are:
>
> `::CU_DEVICE_P2P_ATTRIBUTE_PERFORMANCE_RANK`: A relative value indicating the performance of the link between two devices.
>
> `::CU_DEVICE_P2P_ATTRIBUTE_ACCESS_SUPPORTED` P2`:`1` if P2P Access is enable.
>
> `::CU_DEVICE_P2P_ATTRIBUTE_NATIVE_ATOMIC_SUPPORTED: 1` if Atomic operations over the link are supported.

The name `CU_DEVICE_ATTRUBUTE_ACCESS_SUPPORTED` would suggest that a call to  `cuDeviceCanAccessPeer` is the same as using `cuDeviceGetP2PAttribute` with `attrib` set to `::CU_DEVICE_P2P_ATTRIBUTE_ACCESS_SUPPORTED P2P`, but the description "`1` if P2P Access is enable" confuses me.

Are they really the same, or the second one is supposed to test if the link has been activated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe they are the same.

- `cuDeviceCanAccessPeer` returns whether P2P access is *possible* between two devices or not.
- `cuDeviceGetP2PAttribute`returns whether P2P access is *enabled* between two devices.

Without a prior successful call to `cuCtxEnablePeerAccess`, `cuDeviceGetP2PAttribute` should return false when queried for the `CU_DEVICE_P2P_ATTRIBUTE_ACCESS_SUPPORTED` attribute, even if `cuDeviceCanAccessPeer` returns true.

Note that I also don't presently have access to a P2P enabled system to check this.

Comment: It seems so, but on the other hand the attribute name `CU_DEVICE_P2P_ATTRIBUTE_ACCESS_SUPPORTED` confuses me a bit.